# The font size of chart on android device is different from on iOS device and on Simulator

Tags: codenameone

This issue happens on the pie charts, time series charts, and line charts. I have an example on the pie chart.
I have a medium font declared as follows:
public static Font medFont = Font.createTrueTypeFont("Noto Sans CJK TC Light", "Noto Sans CJK TC Light.ttf").derive(36f, Style.UNIT_TYPE_DIPS);

And set the label of the pie chart as follows:
renderer.setLabelsTextSize(medFont.getHeight()/2);

the pie chart on the simulator with Samsung Galaxy s7 Skin
[image]

the pie chart on an iOS device - iPhone 7 plus
[image]

the pie char on an Android device -Samsung A31
[image]

Comment: Charts are pretty problematic in that sense since they render everything on their own. I'm afraid there's not much we can do other than adapt things individually.